# How to Read In Fixed Width File Using SSIS with Multiple Lines Into SQL Server 2008 DB Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have attempted numerous ways and i have also researched the topic on the Internet only to find single line fixed width files being read in using Flat File Connection. How do you do this when you have three or more differing lines?

Comment: What do you mean by "differing lines"? Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804151/ssis-2005-how-to-import-a-fixed-width-flat-file)? And what "numerous ways" have you attempted and why didn't they work (so people won't suggest what you've already tried)?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the Flat File Connection Manager Editor, ensure you select 'Ragged right' from the Format drop-down list.
The fixed width option is confusing and it is not suitable for a file with a carriage return / line feed at the end of each row.
Once you have selected Ragged right, head to the Advanced section and add every single column that is contained within your text file to the list and set its InputColumnWidth and OutputColumnWidth.
These values represent in the length of each column within your text file.